# How to export HTML table to excel using angularjs/ javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written below code to download file.
It is working for the limited record. now my record count is more that 12000.
Then it is hanging the browser and file not downloaded

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
var edgetype = ua.indexOf("Edge");
var blobObject;
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
    expExcelIframe.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    expExcelIframe.document.write(html);
    expExcelIframe.document.close();
    expExcelIframe.focus();
    expExcelIframe.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, fileName);
}
else if (edgetype > 0) {
    blobObject = new Blob([html]);
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, fileName);
}
else {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
}
```

Comment: Any alternative code to save the file in excel format

Comment: Why do you want an alternative method? What is wrong with that method?

Comment: Which case fails? msie, edgeType, or other?

Comment: if record count more than thousand it is taking more time and browser hangs

Answer (score 0):

Replace `encodeURIComponent`:

> SLOW
>
> ```
> window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
> ```

## Better

```
var blob = new Blob([html],{type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel' });
var u = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(u);
```

This avoids the memory and computation intensive step of converting to base64.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but now i am getting "Error: Access is denied.".Could you please suggest on this.